# when j is initalised and assigned and when j is intiliased but not assigned showing different output please explain - For nested loops

Tags: c

Hey can someone explain me why they are showing different outputs when j is not assinged and not assinged but only intialissed

**when j is assinged as 0**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    
    for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,i*j);
        }        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**when j is not assinged but initalised**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    
    for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        for(int j; j<=i; j++)
        {
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,i*j);
        }        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output : [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have a bit confusion in wording. In the second snippet `j` is **not** initialized. The "assignment" during definition of the variable is called initialization.

Comment: What value do you expect `j` to have without providing an initialization value? Why?

Comment: Please show textual information as text, not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: Oh Okay, Thank you so much for correcting me. Yes, I know there so many mistakes, will try to not repeat it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix up variable definition, initalization and assignment.

A statement like

```
int j = 0;
```

defines *and initializes* the variable `j`. It is however not an assignment.

A statement like

```
int j;
```

only *defines* the variable `j` but does not initialize it.

It doesn't matter if the definition is part of a `for` statement or not.

Uninitialized non-static variables inside functions will be uninitialized, and have an *indeterminate* (seemingly random or garbage) value. Depending on this indeterminate value and the type, it could even lead to *undefined behavior* to use this value.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case,

```
 for(int j; j<=i; j++)
```

`j` is **neither** initialized **nor** assigned an initial value, so in the beginning it contains an indeterminate value. Thus, result of evaluation of the conditional statement `j<=i` is not guranteed.